# How can non-ASCII characters be detected in a QString?

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qtcore, qchar

I want to detect if the user has inputted a non-ASCII (otherwise incorrectly known as Unicode) character (for example, り) in a file save dialog box. As I am using Qt, any non-ASCII characters are properly saved in a QString, but I can't figure out how to determine if any of the characters in that string are non-ASCII before converting the string to ASCII. That character above ends up getting written to the filesystem as `ã‚Š`.

Comment: Once I had an isAscii() proposal, but thiago did not like it. You could have written "if (!myString.at(x).isAcii()); then... I guess you will eventually need to use the low-level isascii, etc yourself.

Comment: Do you mean that creating a file with name り makes it save as ã‚Š? If so what are you using to create the file?

Comment: Well, ASCII characters are Unicode, but that's being a bit pedantic.  For your purposes, any character with a value greater than 127 (0x7F) is "Unicode".

Comment: But note that you can choose to write files as UTF8, in which case (if later read with the same attribute) all characters will be preserved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no such a built-in feature in my understanding.

About 1-2 years ago, I was proposing an isAscii() method for QString/QChar to wrap the low-level Unix isacii() and the corresponding Windows function, but it was rejected. You could have written then something like this:

```
bool isUnicode = !myString.at(3).isAcii();
```

I still think this would be a handy feature if you can convince the maintainer. :-)

Other than that, you would need to check against the ascii boundary yourself, I am afraid. You can do this yourself as follows:

```
bool isUnicode = myChar.unicode() > 127;
```

See the documentation for details:

> [ushort QChar::unicode () const](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qchar.html#unicode)
>
> This is an overloaded function.

Answer (score 9):

The simplest way is to check every charachter's code ([QChar::unicode()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qchar.html#unicode)) to be below 128 if you need pure 7-bit [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Answer (score 5):

To write it in compact way without loop, you can use regular expression:

```
bool containsNonASCII = myString.contains(QRegularExpression(QStringLiteral("[^\\x{0000}-\\x{007F}]")));
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me :
isLetterOrNumber()

```
ot_id += QChar((short) b.to_ulong()).isLetterOrNumber() ? QChar((short) b.to_ulong()) : QString("");
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).